# setting translucent true returns wrong indexPath in UICollectionView GetCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionviewcell

Adding code to set Transculent false causes UICollectionView's - GetCell() meathod returns IndexPath = 0 even clicked at different item.

Removing the particular line makes GetCell() to return the correct IndexPath.

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
```

i expect to have both non-transculent navigation bar & correct IndexPath returned from UICollectionView's - GetCell() meathod.

Thanks

Comment: When you don't use the above code it works fine?

Comment: yes! when i comment the line , everything works perfectly

Comment: Can you add more related codes or provide a simple demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Then why do you need the above code may be there could be an alternative to the above?